# How do I configure iron:router after re-organizing the app directory structure?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am getting this iron:router error message after I re-organised my app directory structure

[image: error message displayed after re-organizing app directory]

The reason for re-organizing the directory structure was because my app reloads became ridiculously slow, and my research showed that re-organizing the dirctory structure would help [Ideas for faster reloads](https://forums.meteor.com/t/ideas-for-faster-reloads/26253/22), [Faster meteor reloads](https://medium.com/@lucashansen/faster-meteor-reloads-62cca5b56460#.7ecrmne4o).

How do I configure iron:router after these directory structure changes?

Find below my environment settings

Am running meteor version: METEOR@1.2.1

Below is what my app directory structure looked like prior to the re organizing (...and when iron:router worked flawlessly):

```
/myMeteorApp
myMeteorApp.html
myMeteorApp.js
myMeteorApp.css
--/public/images
```

Below is currently what my app directory structure looks like (when iron:router fails to work):

```
/myMeteorApp
--/client/myMeteorApp.html
--/client/myMeteorApp.css
--/client/myMeteorApp.js
--/imports/api/tasks.js
--/node_modules/myMeteorApp.css
--/public/images
--/public/js
--/public/uploads
--/server/myMeteorApp.js
```

The router configuration in:
    --/client/myMeteorApp.js looks like this:

```
Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate: 'main'

});

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    template: 'home'
});

Router.route('/previewPost');

Router.route('/MerchantHome');
```

The router configuration in:
    --/client/myMeteorApp.html looks like this:

```
<template name="home">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand pgTitle" href="#">Shopping for...</a>
    </div>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#"> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> </a>
    </li>
</ul>    


</div>
</nav>
</template>
```

I hope the given information is sufficient

Comment: Where is the `main` template that is referred to by your router?

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks for the response. Sorry I cant remember how I sorted this issue out.